# Realm Object Server + server performance monitoring

Tags: realm-mobile-platform

I am looking to implement some performance monitoring on my ROS server.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 running on a VPS.  Unfortunately the VPS has no performance statistics.  So I'm looking to install a tool or connect to a server that will help me understand the load the server is experiencing.

I'm specifically considering deploying Prometheus.  Although it looks like quiet an effort to get it running I figure it's the most comprehensive tool available.

Before I start I want to be sure that this is achievable and it will not impact the ROS performance/capability.

Has anyone implemented performance monitoring?  Did you use a particular service or tool and did you use a great document/page to help you install and configure?

Comment: In the end I've chosen to use datadog.  They have a single line install feature that worked a treat and while I've only got 1 server it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Closed.  See my comment, in the end I used Datadog, which appears to be very good.